# How to embed video in website with Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, video, embed

I am workin in mini project with Asp.net

I am trying to display a video in a website but it give me this error

[image]

here is the code

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
      <source src="~/Hotel.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

    </video>
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML5 technology you may use the code below,

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/WebM">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> <br>
```

Keep in mind that Currently, there are 3 supported video formats for the  element: MP4, WebM,Ogg 

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this site will help you: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/10-working-with-video

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all but this is how I solve the problem

I set the web page as defult page and I include the video as a URL like this

```
<video autoplay loop controls="controls" style="height: 273px; width: 490px; position: relative; top: 138px; left: 0px; ">
      <source src="http://localhost:49363/Hotel2.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
```

and it works :) !

Answer (score 0):

For me, the mime type was missing in `Web.Config`:

Adding in `Web.config` under `<configuration>` the following code fixed it:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```